# Google Maps draws a wrong circle, if it's borders reach the south pole

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to draw a circle with given radius and center point. However, for some reasons Google Maps for iOS reverts the result, if the circle reaches south pole.

Here is the result with radius = 6000 km and center in Sydney. It looks just fine:

[image]

But if I set the radius as 7000 km, the result becomes useless:

[image]

Expected result is:

[image]

Code I use for adding the circle is pretty basic:

```
GMSCircle *geoFenceCircle = [[GMSCircle alloc] init];
geoFenceCircle.radius = 6000000; // Meters
geoFenceCircle.position = _sydneyMarker.position;
geoFenceCircle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:0.5];
geoFenceCircle.strokeWidth = 3;
geoFenceCircle.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
geoFenceCircle.map = mapView;
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think it is zoomed..but works fine..GMSCircle does not have zoomLevel as GMSGroundOverlayOptions...!

Comment: Can you please clarify? You say it works fine, but the screenshot I posted shows that it doesn't

Comment: I think because of radius u pass to map it is zoom in or zoom out..
Zoom option is available with mapview as setting region.span.longitudeDelta/region.span.latitudeDelta..(say 0.5).The expected picture u are showing above is visible with browser not on device..

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to get this working properly

Comment: @AndreyGordeev, were you able solve it. Exact same case here.

Comment: @iAmd Switched to `MapKit` and got a similar problem. Here is discussion/solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872162/mkmapview-mkcircle-renders-a-circle-with-too-big-radius