# How to return an annotation array "X" distance from given Lat & Lon?

Tags: objective-c, loops

I want to return an array of X number of annotation from a method that takes a Lat and Lon.

The Problem: Getting stuck on incrementing the given location Lat and Lon (preferably 1 mile north of given location, 1 mile east of given location, 1 mile west of given location or even better - 1 random mile from given location)  -Hope that made sense, thx for the help.

Even better would be 1 mile random direction from given point but really any Lat&Lon incrementation would do. Thx.

this is the general code I have come up with

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
[super... ]


      [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self getPeepsWithinCurrentLocation:[[self deviceLat] floatValue] :[[self deviceLon] floatValue]]];


    }




    -(NSMutableArray *)getPeepsWithinCurrentLocation:(float)currentLat :(float)currentLon{

        NSMutableArray * myArrayOfPeeps  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


          MapAddAnnotation *ann = [[MapAddAnnotation alloc]init];
    //    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];


        int list = 4;

       static float chgLat=0.1, chgLon=0.1;
         static float myLat,myLon;

        for (int i=0; i< list; i++) {

    // get dictionary of peeps
            self.peeps = [self getMyInfo:[self.books objectAtIndex:i]];

    //        myLat = currentLat +chgLat;
    //        myLon = currentLon +chgLon;

            for (double k = 0; k < .5; k+= 0.1) {

                   myLat = currentLat +k;
                   myLon = currentLon +k;

                        NSLog(@"log from new array list %f,%f", myLat,myLon);

                /////  HHHHHMMMMM NOW what ??



            }


            MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
            region.center.latitude = myLat;
            region.center.longitude = myLon;
            region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
            region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
            //  [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];


            ann.title = [self.peeps objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [self.peeps objectForKey:@"nameTextField"], [self.peeps objectForKey:@"lastnameTextField"]]];
            ann.subtitle = [self.peeps objectForKey:@"Titels_TxtField"];
            ann.coordinate = region.center;


            myLat = +0.1;
            myLon = +0.1;


            [myArrayOfPeeps addObject:ann];

            NSLog(@"log from new array list %@, %f,%f", [myArrayOfPeeps objectAtIndex:i], myLat,myLon);

            }

        NSLog(@"log from new array list %@, %@", myArrayOfPeeps, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", currentLat, currentLon]);

        return myArrayOfPeeps;
    }
```

Comment: In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28872162/1548472) we're talking about something similar although in Swift, but maybe the calculations and libraries could help you as I do believe they are available in objective-c as well.

Comment: thx, for the tip.  I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help someone:  I came up with this method to achieve the general goal

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getPeepsWithinCurrentLocation:(float)currentLat :(float)currentLon{


    NSMutableArray * myArrayOfPeeps  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    int z=0;
    float myLa = 0.0,myLo=0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {


        self.peeps = [self.books objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"......peeps....%@", self.peeps);


        for (float x = 0.0; x < 0.2; x+=0.1) {

            currentLat += x;
            currentLon += x;

            NSLog(@".....test float num....%f", x);
        }


        /////  WORkIIN ANNOTAION CODE HERE
            MapAddAnnotation *ann = [[MapAddAnnotation alloc]init];// Custom Annotaion helper Class

        MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
        region.center.latitude = currentLat;
        region.center.longitude = currentLon;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
        //  [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];


        ann.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [self.peeps objectForKey:@"nameTextField"], [self.peeps objectForKey:@"lastnameTextField"]];
        ann.subtitle = [self.peeps objectForKey:@"jobTitls_TxtField"];
        ann.coordinate = region.center;




        [myArrayOfPeeps addObject:ann];

        NSLog(@"log from new array list %@, %i, %@, %f,%f", [self.peeps objectForKey:@"emailTextField"], i, [myArrayOfPeeps objectAtIndex:i], currentLat,currentLon);

        //////////////////////////////////////
        z=i;

        NSLog(@".......test log..in INT loop..%i, %f---, %f", i, myLa, myLo);
    }

    NSLog(@".......test log....%i", [myArrayOfPeeps count] );


    return myArrayOfPeeps;
}
```